# How can I show errors in jQuery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Do we have any function which returns all the error messages while validating a form?

I have tried using the *defaultshowerros()* function but it returns the error message for the element it is currently validating. How can I get all the error messages of the whole form?

Comment: could you provide a link to the validation plugin you are using? Or even better some source code :)

Comment: I am using this plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you store a reference to the validator, for example:

```
var validator = $("form").validate();
```

You can call `.errors()` or `.invalidElements()` at any time on it, for example:

```
var errors = validator.errors(); //get the error elements, the actual labels
var errors = validator.invalidElements(); //the invalid elements themselves
```

If you're not really after the errors and just want them to appear in once place, use the built-in [`errorLabelContainer` and `wrapper` options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), for example:

```
<ul id="errors"></ul>
```

And reference that:

```
$("form").validate({ errorLabelContainer: "#errors", wrapper: "li" });
```

And your errors would appear all in that list, which is also automatically shown/hidden if there are/aren't any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The validation plugin should show an error beside the field where the error is. Are you using id's for your input boxes? If so use a name as well and give jquery the value of the name attribute in your rules and messages. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I found you can also instantiate the `validate()` object with a `invalidHandler()` function:

```
var $jqvForm = $(".jqvForm").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(e, validation){
        console.log("invalidHandler : event", e);
        console.log("invalidHandler : validation", validation);
    }
});
```

The `validation` variable contains a variable `invalid` (object) with form items and their error messages.