# Validation check with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my aspx page, am using some validation controls like required field validator, if I click on save button If the particular field is empty, the validation error fires.

And if I fill that particular field and give tab out, that validation error automatically disappears. My query here is, is it possible to display any message using jQuery or anyother method, until the validation error disappears.

Whenever the validation error appears in that page the message should appear, and if we clear the validation error that message should disappear automatically.I dont know how to do this, coz I dont have much knowledge in jQuery.

Can anyone help me here, thanks in advance

Comment: You can use validation summary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h(v=vs.71).aspx  If you want to create custom validation summary control visit this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8635/Custom-Validation-Summary-in-ASP-NET

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion Meherzad, I just wanted to know is it possible to show the message until the validation errors there in a page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for jQuery showErrors(). There's some good information in this post which might answer your question: [How can I show errors in jQuery validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811044/how-can-i-show-errors-in-jquery-validation)

Comment: Actually, am not using any plugins for validation, am using ASP validation only

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I don't know anything about ASP validation specifically. I don't know whether it could helpful to make use of the jQuery validation in conjunction with the ASP validation, so that jQuery can take care of the error display, but it might be worth a try.